# Why doesn't the API return suggested edits on tag wikis?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, api-v2, tag-wiki

Is there a reason why the API doesn't return suggested edits on tag wikis on the  [suggested-edits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits) route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag wikis, their editing, and the promotion there of are still being actively developed (after something of a lull).

I didn't think it appropriate to expose suggested edits w.r.t. tag wikis at this time accordingly, this will be revisited in the next API revision.

Comment: Is the situation same even in 2017?

Comment: Is the situation same even in 2018?

Comment: continuing the venerable tradition: is the situation the same even in 2021?