# Return suggested edits for tag wikis and excerpts from the API

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

It's time we put the venerable tradition of haunting [Kevin Montrose](https://stackapps.com/users/2/kevin-montrose)'s [answer](https://stackapps.com/a/3173) with comments on when the API will start returning suggested edits for tag wikis and excerpts to rest. This is an official request to start returning them from the [/suggested-edits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits-by-ids) and [/posts/<ids>/suggested-edits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-suggested-edits) endpoints.

It would be highly appreciated if we got `/tags/suggested-edits` and (or) `/tags/<ids>/suggested-edits` endpoints too. If all endpoints require an unreasonable amount of developer time to implement, please, consider adding at least one of the proposed endpoints.

The proposed change will require the [`suggested_edit`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/suggested-edit) type to be updated to include the new suggestion type as a enum member for `post_type` (for example, `"tag-wiki" | "tag-excerpt"`).

There are multiple userscripts (f.e., [RQH](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js), [SRSER](https://stackapps.com/questions/9106/make-suggested-edits-review-tasks-wider)) and curation / moderation chat bots (f.e., [SpotDetector](https://github.com/SOBotics/SpotDetector)) that are forced to rely on brittle hacks to get suggestions for tag wikis and excerpts that would greatly benefit from this long-awaited change. The information would also also help managing tag burninations and its huge backlog, as well as disambiguation requests.